# Mysql trigger to update if date match and insert if no match all BEFORE INSERT

Tags: mysql, validation, triggers, insert

I have a table `summary`. I want a TRIGGER to fire before insert on this table i.e `summary` and what I want is that, the TRIGGER should check if the incoming date matches with existing date, it should update the table and add incoming value to existing value else it should just insert

```
`summary`
+------+-------+-------------+------+
| date |income | expenditure | other|
|22/17 | 200   |   50        |  30  |
|22/17 | 100   |   10        |  80  |
|23/17 | 50    |   100       |  0   |
+------+-------+-------------+------+

`summary` // this is how I want it to be
+------+-------+-------------+------+
| date |income | expenditure | other|
|22/17 | 300   |   150       |  30  |
|23/17 | 50    |   100       |  0   |
+------+-------+-------------+------+
```

my table code

```
CREATE TABLE `summary` (
  `id_` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_` date NOT NULL,
  `income_` text NOT NULL,
  `expenditure_` text NOT NULL,
  `other_` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `summary` 
(`id_`, `date_`, `income_`, `expenditure_`, `other_`)
VALUES
(1, '2017-12-22', 200, 50, 30),
(2, '2017-12-22', 100, 10, 80),
(3, '2017-12-23', 50, 100, 0);
```

This is what I have been trying so far, though am a Novist 
trigger code

```
DELIMITER
$$
CREATE TRIGGER inc_trig 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON income_
FOR EaCH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE income,expenditure,other INT;

SET income=1; SET expenditure=2; SET other=3;

IF( NEW.date_ != date_ )THEN

IF NEW.name_ = income THEN
INSERT INTO summary (date_,income)
VALUES (new.date_,new.amount);

ELSEIF NEW.name_ = expenditure THEN
INSERT INTO summary (date_,expenditure_)
VALUES (new.date_,new.amount);

ELSEIF NEW.name_ = other THEN
INSERT INTO summary (date_,other_)
VALUES (new.date_,new.amount);


ELSE(new.date_ = date_)THEN

IF NEW.name_ = income_ THEN
UPDATE summary SET income_ = income_ + new.amount);

ELSEIF NEW.name_ = expenditure THEN
UPDATE summary SET expenditure_ = expenditure_ + new.amount);

ELSEIF NEW.name_ = other THEN
UPDATE summary SET other_ = other_ + new.amount);


END IF;

END
$$
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a much easier approach. First, add a `unique` constraint on your `date` column to prevent duplicate entries:

```
ALTER TABLE summary ADD CONSTRAINT summary_date_uniq UNIQUE(`date`);
```

And then use the [`on duplicate key update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax when inserting new data:

```
INSERT INTO summary
(`date_`, `income_`, `expenditure_`, `other_`)
VALUES (2, '2017-12-22', 100, 10, 80)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`income` = `income_` + VALUES(`income_`),
`expenditure` = `expenditure_` + VALUES(`expenditure_`),
`others` = `others_` + VALUES(`others_`);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply..bit i am having this error unknown column  income if i try to insert into income column and so on

Comment: @JoshuaSampson just looked at your DDL again. For some obscure reason, all your column names end with `_`. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: i am  trying to update his to what am doing,the reason why i made every thing short was that the code am working with is too long maybe i should post it cause this is not working